# Is is possible to do only one db call in ActiveRecord's `uniqueness` check?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm going through RoR tutorial book and I'm at the model validation part. This is how my model looks atm:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates(:name,
    presence: true,
    length: { maximum: 80 },
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
  )

  validates(:pass,
    presence: true,
  )

  validates(:email,
    presence: true,
    length: { maximum: 254 },
    format: { with: /.*@.*\..*/ },
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
  )

  before_save { email.downcase! }
end
```

however, what I've noticed in `rails console` is that this produces
two sql queries with each `.valid?` call.

```
[wolf@devel web]$ r console --sandbox
Running via Spring preloader in process 20864
Loading development environment in sandbox (Rails 5.2.1)
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit
2.5.0 :001 > User.new.valid?
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."name" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => false
```

is this required for the reporting of what validations where broken? Is there a way around this
to reduced number of roundtrips to the db?

Comment: you could get around this by writing your own `validate` block manually.

Comment: hm, I guess I'll just move the uniq check into the database, it need to be (also) there anyway to protect from race conditions, right?

Comment: The "race conditions" would exist even with one validation check. Transactions and/or database-level constraints (ie. unique indices) are required.

Comment: I know, I meant that since I have to expect `RecordNotUnique` exception anyway, does the check in model (for uniqueness) bring any value to the table? So i'm thinking of dropping it all together and rely on db to detect duplicates

Comment: Validations are nice precisely because they are *not* strictly tied to the database - ie. can validate a field without commitment insert/update - `valid?`. This catches "most" user validation ("Please choose a different name, that account was already taken!"). DB constraints are for final data enforcement, but are generally harder to report a user-friendly message. DB constraints cover the *rare, but possible* cases where a user will get a "500: Oops, try again!" when creating a new account. Transactions are used as relevant for DB consistency/atomicity.

Comment: hm, I did not think about the report-error part, I guess that's true, thank you

Comment: Without the validation you'll get a database driver exception every time a user attempts to create a duplicate - instead of just triggering a model validation.